# Comma seperated values into a list

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, generics

I'm using a postcode lookup service provided online using a class they provide.

The returned information is a list of addresses in the format

```
<XmlRootAttribute("Addresses")> _
Public Class Addresses
    <XmlElementAttribute("Address")> _
    Public Address As List(Of Address)
End Class
```

where Address is

```
Public Class Address

    Public organisation As String
    Public premise As String
    Public dependentstreet As String
    Public street As String
    Public doubledependentlocality As String
    Public dependentlocality As String
    Public posttown As String
    Public county As String
    Public postcode As String

    Public summaryline As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return summaryline
    End Function

End Class
```

The summaryline property returns a comma separated list of the Address class (e.g)

**Fox Road, Framingham Pigot, Norwich, Norfolk, NR14 7PZ**

I'm using this list of returned addresses to populate a dropdownlist, which will then split up the selected address into "Address 1", "Address 2", "Town" etc.

In the code example provided they are using a Windows Form and populate a Combobox and the line that splits the comma seperated address into an Address class is this line

```
Dim address As Address = DirectCast(addresses_ComboBox.SelectedItem, Address)

organisation_TextBox.Text = address.organisation
premise_TextBox.Text = address.premise
dependentStreet_TextBox.Text = address.dependentstreet
street_TextBox.Text = address.street
doubleDependentLocality_TextBox.Text = address.doubledependentlocality
locality_TextBox.Text = address.dependentlocality
town_TextBox.Text = address.posttown
county_TextBox.Text = address.county
postcode_TextBox.Text = address.postcode
```

Is there a way for me to convert that top line but using  dropdownlist.SelectedValue instead of addresses_ComboBox.SelectedItem

I can split the string into an array but not all addresses have all of the Address class properties returned.  Some addresses may not have a Premise for example so I can't convert the comma separated address back into the Address class perfectly into each property.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: If you have a class with all the properties you need separated into their own properties, why on Earth wouldn't you use that? Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am using it.  I return a list of found Addresses and use it to populate a dropdownlist.

The user then selects the correct address but I need to populate an instance of the Address class correctly.  Because some addresses don't have all of the Address properties I can't just split my summaryline string as I am at the moment, I need to Cast is back into an instance of Address

Comment: But if your drop down is populated with instances of `Address` why on Earth do you need to recreate a new instance of `Address`? And why would use use the completely unreliable `summaryline` to do it instead of the actual properties? You are going about this all wrong. `summaryline` is clearly *only* useful for displaying to the user. It is completely useless for reconstructing the `Address` object.

Comment: I think that's where I'm getting confused, I'm not populating the DDL with instances of Address, simply using the summaryline as the value of the DDL item.  (My .NET isn't the greatest as you can tell)

Comment: @ScottJackson: I don't know how and asp.net DropDownList works. The Windows Forms example you were given presumably works because you can add any object (an Address object in this case) to a ComboBox. The object's ToString method is used to decide what to display to the user, but the ComboBox item is still the Address object so when the user selects an item, you have the object you want. If DropDownList doesn't let you do that, you will need to save the Address objects somewhere (perhaps in a list) and keep track of which DropDownList item corresponds to which item in your list.

Comment: Not sure if it is the correct way to do it Blackwood but I have populated my dropdown with the Address objects and then I use the ddl selectedvalue to find the correct object in my returned list of address and it's working fine.  I have the correct Address instance to use.  Thanks a lot for your helpful tone

Comment: @ScottJackson : please ask to the user who helped you most to post an answer, you'll be able to accept it in order to marked this question as solved.